# lambda.1se not being in one standard error of the error

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso-regression

In the documentation of the function [`cv.glmnet()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-10/topics/cv.glmnet), it is given that:

> lambda.1se  :
> largest value of lambda such that error is within 1 standard error of the minimum.

Which means that `lambda.1se` gives the `lambda`, which gives an error (`cvm`) which is one standard error away from the minimum error.

So, while trying to check this fact:
There is a data set `Boston` in the library `MASS`. I performed a cross validation, using the lasso:

```
x = model.matrix(crim~.-1,data=Boston)#-1 for removing the intercept column
y = Boston$crim
cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x,y,type.measure = "mse",alpha=1)
```

And the value of `cv.lasso$lambda.min` comes out to be:

```
> cv.lasso$lambda.min
[1] 0.05630926
```

And, the value of `cv.lasso$lambda.1se` is:

```
> cv.lasso$lambda.1se
[1] 3.375651
```

Now, look at this:

```
> std(cv.lasso$cvm)
[1] 0.7177808
```

Where `std` is a function, that returns the standard error of the values inserted in it.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azk6H.png)
And the minimum value of `cvm` can be found as:

```
> cv.lasso$cvm[cv.lasso$lambda==cv.lasso$lambda.min]
[1] 42.95009
```

So, we add the standard error to the value of `cvm`  and we get:

```
> 42.95009+0.7177808
[1] 43.66787
```

Even though there is no `lambda` value corresponding to this `cvm` value, we can have an idea on the basis of existing data:
[image]

Which means `lambda.1se` should be between 0.4784899 and 0.4359821. But that's absolutely not the case. So, there's a gut feeling that says I'm making a blunder here. Can you help me point at that?

---

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azk6H.png):Definition of `std`:

```
std<-function(x)
  sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll add a seed so one can replicate the results below:

```
library(glmnet)
library(MASS)
data("Boston")
x = model.matrix(crim~.-1,data=Boston)#-1 for removing the intercept column
y = Boston$crim
set.seed(100)
cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x,y,type.measure = "mse",alpha=1)
```

The minimum cross-validated MSE is `min(cv.lasso$cvm) = 43.51256`. The corresponding lambda is `cv.lasso$lambda.min = 0.01843874`. The `lambda.1se` is `cv.lasso$lambda.1se = 3.375651`. This corresponds to a cross-validated MSE of

```
cv.lasso$cvm[which(cv.lasso$lambda == cv.lasso$lambda.1se)] = 57.5393
```

We can access the cross-validated standard errors directly from GLMNET's output as follows:

```
cv.lasso$cvsd[which(cv.lasso$lambda == cv.lasso$lambda.min)] = 15.40236
```

So the cross-validated MSE one standard error away is

```
43.51256 + 15.40236 = 58.91492
```

This is just slightly higher than the cross-validated MSE at `lambda.1se` above (i.e. `57.5393`). If we look at the cross-validated MSE at the `lambda` just before the `lambda.1se`, it is:

```
cv.lasso$cvm[which(cv.lasso$lambda == cv.lasso$lambda.1se)-1] = 59.89079
```

So now that we can reconcile GLMNET's output, let me explain why you are not getting the same thing using your calculation:

1. `cv.lasso$cvm` contains the cross-validated mean MSE for each value of `lambda`.
2. When we say 1 standard error, we are not talking about the standard error across the lambda's but the standard error across the folds for a given lambda.
3. Continuing with the above point, at `lambda.min`, we have 10 folds. We fit 10 models and have 10 out-of-sample MSE's. The mean of these 10 MSE's is given by `cv.lasso$cvm[which(cv.lasso$lambda == cv.lasso$lambda.min)]`. The standard deviation of these 10 MSE's is given by `cv.lasso$cvsd[which(cv.lasso$lambda == cv.lasso$lambda.min)]`. What we are not given in the GLMNET output are the 10 MSE's at `lambda.min`. If we had this, then we should be able to replicate the the standard error by using the formula you have above.

Let me know if this helps.

EDIT: Let's do an example whereby we define in advance three folds

```
set.seed(100)
folds = sample(1:3, nrow(x), replace = T)
cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x,y,type.measure = "mse",alpha=1, keep =T, foldid = folds)
```

Note that

```
> min(cv.lasso$cvm)
[1] 42.76584
> cv.lasso$cvsd[which.min(cv.lasso$cvm)]
[1] 17.89725
```

(These differ from the earlier example above because we've defined our own folds)

Note also that I have an additional parameter `keep = T` in the `cv.glmnet` call. This returns the fold predictions for each lambda. You can extract them for the optimal lambda by doing:

```
cv.lasso$fit.preval[,which.min(cv.lasso$cvm)]
```

Before we proceed, let's create a data frame with the response, the fold predictions, and the corresponding folds:

```
library(data.table)
OOSPred = data.table(y = y, 
                     predictions = cv.lasso$fit.preval[,which.min(cv.lasso$cvm)], 
                     folds = folds)
```

Here is a preview of the first 10 rows:

```
> head(OOSPred, 10)
          y predictions folds
 1: 0.00632  -0.7477977     1
 2: 0.02731  -1.3823830     1
 3: 0.02729  -3.4826143     2
 4: 0.03237  -4.4419795     1
 5: 0.06905  -3.4373021     2
 6: 0.02985  -2.5256505     2
 7: 0.08829   0.7343478     3
 8: 0.14455   1.1262462     2
 9: 0.21124   4.0507847     2
10: 0.17004   0.5859587     1
```

For example, for the cases where `folds = 1`, a model was built on folds #2 & #3 and then predictions were obtained for the observations in fold #1. We compute the MSE by fold now:

```
OOSPredSum = OOSPred[, list(MSE = mean((y - predictions)^2)), by = folds]

   folds      MSE
1:     1 27.51469
2:     2 75.72847
3:     3 19.93480
```

Finally, we return the mean MSE and standard error of the MSE across the folds

```
> OOSPredSum[, list("Mean MSE" = mean(MSE), "Standard Error" = sd(MSE)/sqrt(3))]
   Mean MSE Standard Error
1: 41.05932       17.47213
```

GLMNET may be performing a weighted mean and standard error (weighted by the number of observations in each fold), which is why the figures above a close but do not match exactly.

Comment: I think you mean "This is just slightly higher than the cross-validated MSE at **`lambda.1se`**".

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So, your third point says that for each `lambda` value, we fit 10(exactly?) models which are produced by randomly selecting the 10 folds of cross-validation. Now, we fit these models, and find the MSE for each of these models. The `cvm` value is eventually, the mean of these MSEs. Thus we get a corresponding `cvm` for each `lambda` which is dependent upon the folds that cross-validation selects. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have added an example above to illustrate this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the procedure is:

1. For each **ƛ** it creates **x** models ( **x =** **nº of folds** in which the data set has been splitted for cross-validation algorithm)
2. For each **ƛ** and each model **x**, it calculates the mean(error) and sd(error), thus, mean(x errors) and sd(x errors)
3. Let's say that we have **ƛmin** and **serrorƛmin** (calculated in step 2.). Now, **ƛse** is defined as *"largest value of lambda such that error is within 1 standard error of the minimum"*. Then the condition for **ƛse** is:

   **ƛse** in [**ƛmin** - **seƛmin**, **ƛmin** + **seƛmin**]
4. Then **ƛse** =  max(ƛ),ƛ where  which fulfills the condition above.

I can show you an example:

```
lasso_cv <- cv.glmnet(x = x, y= endpoint, alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas_to_try,
                  standardize = TRUE, nfolds = 10,type.measure="auc",
                  family="binomial")
```

Note that **ƛmin** is:

```
lasso_cv$lambda.min
[1] 0.007742637
```

And **serrorƛmin** is:

```
serrorlmin <- lasso_cv$cvsd[which(lasso_cv$lambda == lasso_cv$lambda.min)]
serrorlmin

[1] 0.01058009
```

Then, the range in which **ƛse** is chosen is:

```
rang <- c(lasso_cv$lambda.min - serrorlmin,lasso_cv$lambda.min + serrorlmin)
[1] -0.002837457  0.018322731
```

And to find it:

```
max(lasso_cv$lambda[lasso_cv$lambda>=rang[1] & lasso_cv$lambda<=rang[2]])
[1] 0.01629751
```

And this value matches with **ƛse**!

```
lasso_cv$lambda.1se # 0.01629751
```

I hope it helps!